# Laravel Increase SQL speed

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to increase the speed of my queries in **Laravel 5.7** and I have the call down to ~2.5 seconds. I am trying to figure out more ways to make it faster and if I could get some help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

How my data is structured: [image]

Function(Controller):

```
public function getUserDataTmp(Request $request) {

        $input = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $request = json_decode($input);

        if ($this->authTokenAccess($request) == true) {

            $bottomWords = bottom_exterior_word::select('word','sentence','sequence','id','group_id')->where('user_id','=', $request->id)->get();

            $emergencyWords = left_exterior_word::select('word','sentence','sequence','id')->where('user_id','=', $request->id)->get();

            foreach($bottomWords as $tmp => $key) {
                $group_id = $key->group_id;
                $bottomWords->user_id = $request->id;
                $bottomWords[$tmp]->words = $key->getMainWords($group_id, $request->id);
            }

            foreach($emergencyWords as $key => $word) {
                $emergencyWords[$key]->image = imageModel::select('base64','id')->where('emergency_id','=', $word->id)->first();

            }

            $data = [
                'data' => [
                    'return' => 'success',
                    'code' => 'VEDC001',
                    'response' => 'Successfully Gathered Words',
                    'main_categories' => $bottomWords,
                    'emergency_words' => $emergencyWords
                ]
            ];

            return(json_encode($data));

        }

    }
```

getMainWords Function(bottom_exterior_word model):

```
    public function getMainWords($group_id, $id)
  {
      // return("TEST");
      $words = \App\main_word::select('id','group_id','sentence','sequence','word')->where('group_id','=', $group_id)->where('user_id','=', $id)->get();
      foreach ($words as $key => $word) {
          $words[$key]->image = Image::select('base64','id')->where('word_id','=', $word->id)->first();
      }
      return $words;
  }
```

Comment: Do you have indexes?

Comment: @Snapey I have a primary key that auto increments for the main words and everything uses that key(word_id).

Comment: @ImJT I would start by refactoring so that no queries are called inside `foreach` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old post, would just like to update it though. Since I have first posted this, I have learned a lot more about Laravel and am a lot more experienced with it.

Here is my new function and solution:

Controller:

```
public function data(Request $request)
{
    return response()->success(
        [
            'emergencywords' => EmergencyWord::with('image')->whereUserId($request->user()->id)->get(),
            'categorywords' => CategoryWord::with(['image','words.image'])->whereUserId($request->user()->id)->get(),
        ]
    );
}
```

Category Word Relationships:

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Image','id','image_id');
}

public function words()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\MainWord','category_words_id','sequence');
}
```

Emergency Word Relationships:

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Image','id','image_id');
}
```

Main Word Relationships:

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Image','id','image_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by refactoring so that you dont query inside a `foreach` loop

```
foreach($bottomWords as $tmp => $key) {
            $group_id = $key->group_id;
            $bottomWords->user_id = $request->id;
            $bottomWords[$tmp]->words = $key->getMainWords($group_id, $request->id);
        }
```

I would change the `getMainWords` function to accepts an array of group id's and use the `whereIn` clause:

> The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained
>   within the given array:
>
> $users = DB::table('users')
>                       ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
>                       ->get();

Same treatment for this loop.

```
        foreach($emergencyWords as $key => $word) {
            $emergencyWords[$key]->image = imageModel::select('base64','id')->where('emergency_id','=', $word->id)->first();

        }
```

In general minimizing the NUMBER of queries will improve response time.